# How to Change Rows of Arrays into Opposite

Tags: google-sheets, join, split, flatten, google-query-language

I have a Sheet with Column A being City and Column B being District, like so:

| City | Districts |
| --- | --- |
| Accord | 103 |
| Albany | 109,110,108 |
| Altamont | 109 |

I would like to transform this into the "opposite":

| District | Cities |
| --- | --- |
| 103 | Accord |
| 108 | Albany |
| 109 | Albany, Altamont |
| 110 | Albany |

I'm pretty sure it's simple.  Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(FLATTEN(
 QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(B2:B, ",")&"¤×"&A2:A&","), "×"), 
 "select max(Col2) group by Col2 pivot Col1"),,9^9))), 
 ",$", ), "¤ ", 0), "where Col2 is not null", 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's neat!